# Finding highest weight of a $gl(3)$ submodule of a $gl(4)$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, mathematical-physics

We have $gl(3)\subset gl(4)$. I have a $gl(n)$  $V(3,2,1,0)$-module.

I want to know two things:

> 1) What is the $gl(3,\Bbb C)\subset gl(4,\Bbb C)$ branching rule for the $gl(n)$ $V(3,2,1,0)$-module.
>
> 2) What is the highest weight vector of $gl(n-1)$ as a subalgebra of $gl(n)$ with highest weight vector $(3,2,1,0)$?

---

It seems the Branching rule requires $(3,2,1,0)=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4)$ which is our weight of our highest weight vector, to give us $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)$ for the highest weight vector of the $gl(3)$-submodule, via the rule $\lambda_i - \mu_i \geq 0$ and $\mu_i - \lambda_{i+1}\geq 0$(integers).

So we have:

\begin{align}
3-\mu_1 \geq 0\quad\quad\mu_1 -2\geq 0\\
2-\mu_2 \geq 0\quad\quad \mu_2 -1\geq 0\\
1-\mu_3 \geq 0\quad\quad \mu_3 - 0 \geq0
\end{align}
Giving us:
\begin{align}
3\geq \mu_1 \geq 2\\
2\geq \mu_2 \geq 1\\
1\geq \mu_3 \geq 0\\
\end{align}

Which gives us $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)=(3,2,1),(3,2,0),(3,1,1),(3,1,0),(2,2,1),(2,2,0),(2,1,1),(2,1,0)$

> Then (**for 2)**) all of these are highest weight vectors of the $gl(3)$-submodule?

And the branching rule (**for 1)**) I 'think' says that :

$$V(3,2,1,0)|_{gl(3)} = V'(3,2,1) \oplus V'(3,2,0) \oplus V'(3,1,1) \oplus V'(3,1,0) \oplus V'(2,2,1) \oplus V'(2,2,0 )\oplus V'(2,1,1) \oplus V'(2,1,0)$$

Maybe I could verify if I knew the dimension of the LHS&RHS, which I do know how to determine using Weyl's dimension formula, but it would be extremely long winded, and I suspect hopefully there is a better way.